# How can I redo something every minute in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, scheduled-tasks

how can I loop print something 5 times every minute like when 09.01 am print something 5 times then do nothing till 09.02 am and print  other things 5 times then do nothing

Comment: Does this answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377454/how-do-i-get-my-python-program-to-sleep-for-50-milliseconds

Comment: No, assume I give you to do work at 10.00 when you are done you can take a rest but when 11.00 you will do new work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling tasks using Python's Schedule module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444329/scheduling-tasks-using-pythons-schedule-module). See also [Schedule a repeating event in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398661/schedule-a-repeating-event-in-python-3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schedule a repeating event in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398661/schedule-a-repeating-event-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some elements of answer:

- `datetime.datetime.now()` gives you the time of, well, now. Use it to check whether it's 10 am
- `time.sleep` allows you to pause your program for a given number of second (say 60 to make 1 minute)
- `while True` allows you to run a program continuously

Also, note that it is probably not the best approach. On linux and mac you have utilities such as [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) to do that. Pretty sure something exists on Windows as well. Bottom line: scheduling is best managed by your os, not by a python script.

Comment: guess you might also want to point to something async; typically you don't want the timer of your scheduled task block all the rest of your code

Comment: @MrFuppes true that

Comment: Thanks, everyone, that exactly what I wanted to do.